# Multithreading PhantomJS using Pool.map() Type Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My code prints out the  error **TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object** when executed. 
My objective was to parallerize Ajax scraping using selenium since I din't quite know how to scrape Ajax calls directly.
My end goal is to replace the number list ***a=[1,2,3,4]*** with a list of urls, ***a=['url1','url2',...]***
for screen scraping.(this is just 'prototype' code).
I'll appreciate a simple but accurate explanation of the solution since am not that good at programming.Thanks.`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium import webdriver

def func(x):
    y=x[0]
    return y*y


if __name__=='__main__':
    a=[1,2,3,4]
    drivers=[webdriver.PhantomJS() for x in range(4)]
    c=zip(a,drivers)
    p=Pool(4)
    results=p.map(func,c)
    p.close()
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Comment: You are using multiprocessing. It is different than multithreading. Threads are sharing memory, processes are not. For pure python parallel program, you want to use multiprocessing because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Not knowing selenium, I do not know why this error was raised, but could you tell us which line raised it, the `zip()` or the `map()`?

Comment: @Mathieu: The 'results=p.map(func,c) ' line raised the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about `selenium` or `webdriver` it is clear that it opens a `TextIOWrapper` object. Exactly why, I do not know, but it could be e.g. a wrapped file index or a socket. The problem is that this object cannot be serialized and passed between your different processes.

The simplest solution in the current case is to instead let each process instantiate its own `driver` and just pass the indata and return the result to the main process:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium import webdriver

def func(x):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # To be used in current function (process)
    y = x
    return y*y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    p = Pool(4)
    results = p.map(func, a)
    p.close()
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Note, thought, that this does not work if you want to keep the `driver`s alive to be used for more actions later. In that case you need a more elaborate scheme where you set up your processes ahead of time (using the `initializer` argument when creating your `Pool`).

Comment: :Thanks a bunch. It makes more sense to let each process instantiate it's own driver!! Oh and you've kinda set the path for researching I need to do.